# python: Writing Application- Different modules/Licenses and impact on Proprietary application

Tags: python, licensing, commercial-application

I've written an application using wxPython and various other small modules (xlrd, xlwrt, pyserial, etc.) xlrd/xlwt i believe use a BSD license, and wxPython..

```
    ""Being a wrapper, wxPython uses the same free software licence 
used by wxWidgets (wxWindows License)—which is approved by Free 
Software Foundation and Open Source /n Initiative"" -wikipedia entry on wxPython
```

Just wondering about the implications of selling an application like this. I'm new to all this and am wondering what it means to use  GPL-compatible modules, what the "free software foundation" is about, etc.

I.e., is the purpose of the free software foundation to restrict the use of 'open source', 'free-ware' code/modules from being bundled into commerical applications? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"GPL-compatible" only matters if you're writing GPLed or LGPLed code. When writing a proprietary application the biggest concern is "closed-source-incompatible", although a proprietary app does not *necessarily* need to be closed-source. BSD and LGPL (among others) are closed-source-compatible; GPL is not.